# facebook group post graph api not allowing me to post

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-group

I am trying to post to one of my group but getting below error

> Graph returned an error: (#200) If posting to a group, requires app being installed in the group, and \ either publish_to_groups permission with user token, or both manage_pages \ and publish_pages permission with page token; If posting to a page, \ requires both manage_pages and publish_pages as an admin with \ sufficient administrative permission

using below code

```
$page_token = "";
$group_id = "1258454427550445";

try {
        $publish = $fb->post('/'.$group_id.'/feed',array('message'=>$_POST['status'] .'   via phplift.net demos'),$page_token);
        } catch(\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
            // When Graph returns an error
            echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            exit;
          } catch(\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
            // When validation fails or other local issues
            echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            exit;
          }

        echo 'Status updated.<br>';
```

its saying on [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v5.0/group/feed#publish):

**App Installation**

Group admins can locate and install your app as described in the Help Center, [How do I add an app](https://web.facebook.com/help/261149227954100?_rdc=1&_rdr).

I am following all steps but unable to find my app on my group to add please guide me how i can add my app to my group.

Comment: I'd guess that only reviewed & approved live apps show up in that place. The documentation on posting to a group feed does not have specific instructions how you have to set stuff up to be able to test this in dev mode. I'd try logging into Facebook as one of the app's test users, have them create a group, and test with that (if possible, I haven't checked.)

Comment: I have the same problem. No answer for almost three years?